# Low internet speed on newest kernels using rtl8188eus

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, drivers

For some reason, starting with kernel 5.15~ my net speed drop to like a 15% of what I get with previous ones. I have a TP-Link TL-WN725N that uses the RTL8188EUS driver and I know that's pretty crappy on Linux, but aside from some random disconnections it worked well until latest updates.

Tried some other drivers I found on github but no luck. Currently the latest kernel I have installed is 5.16.9-200.fc35, but I'm still stuck on 5.14.17-301.fc35, which is the last one in which the wifi works normally.

Also, I'm using Fedora Workstation 35.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Then stick with 5.14 unless you have a reason to need 5.16. Later doesn't necessarily mean "better".

Comment: @JeremyBoden yeah, for now, it seems to be the easiest fix